# DataTables not preserving ticked checkboxes across pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

my issue is that my datatable is not keeping the checked state of selected rows when changing between tables.

The code for my table

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var userGroupData = @Html.Raw(Model.UserGroupJson);
    var table = $('#usergroupTarget').DataTable({
        "data": userGroupData,
        "columns": [
            {"title": "Usergroup Name"},
            {"title": "Target"}
        ],

        "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
            var tblTds = $('>td', nRow);
            tblTds[0].innerHTML = aData[1];

            $(nRow).attr("id", 'tblRow_' + aData[0]);
            tblTds[1].innerHTML = '<td><input type="checkbox" name="publishedstatus" value="' + aData[0] + '" id="' + aData[0] + '" onclick="Member(' + aData[0] + ')" /><label for="' + aData[0] + '"></label>></td>';
        }
    })
});
```

Html:

```
                                   <table id="usergroupTarget" class="display table table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Usergroup Name</th>
                                            <th>Target</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                </table>
```

One suggestion that I found which seemed to make sense was to set "bServerSide": false   so that the checkbox ticks were preserved locally but this didn't work.

Thanks

Comment: You mention two tables. Where is the code for your second table?

Comment: Sorry I should have said when swapping between pages on the same table.